# Text parsing and retrieval

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to write a script letting me parse a text file. Every time I have `ACTION TYPE: Insertion` I will need to retrieve the `TIME` value below.

```
ACTION TYPE: Insertion
ISSUES: No
USER: ADMINISTRATOR
TIME: 2015-10-09 10.50.12
ACTION TYPE: Edition
ISSUES: No
USER: ADMINISTRATOR
TIME: 2015-10-09 11.21.34
ACTION TYPE: Insertion
ISSUES: No
USER: ADMINISTRATOR
TIME: 2015-10-09 12.19.22
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: If you're asking how to open a file and read its contents, [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) should be useful to you.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: Why would you edit to make it worse again?!

Comment: Kevin: it is about opening, reading and then extracting specific data if a condition is verified.
MArtin: i want to parse a log file which can contains tens or thousands lines.

Answer (score 1):

For small files where the whole file can be easily loaded into memory, the following approach could be used:

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    print re.findall(r'ACTION TYPE: Insertion.*?TIME: (.*?)$', f_input.read(), re.M+re.S)
```

Which would display the following for your sample:

```
['2015-10-09 10.50.12', '2015-10-09 12.19.22']
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as Martin Evans, but with a more simplistic pattern:

```
import re
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    pat = re.compile(r'ACTION TYPE: Insertion\nISSUES: .*\nUSER: .*\nTIME: (.*)')
    insertion_times = re.findall(pat, f.read())
```